# How to trace an error when there is no output in the console window?

Tags: ubuntu, console, wkhtmltopdf

I've followed a tutorial located [here](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/wiki/Getting-Started-Installing-wkhtmltopdf) on how to install the static version of wkhtmltopdf on an Ubuntu server (the one with additional features compared to the one on the apt-get repo).

I've followed all steps in the guide correctly as you can see in this GIF:

[image]

As shown in the GIF there is no output at all when I type the command `wkhtmltopdf` on it's own, or any parameters after the command. E.g `wkhtmltopdf -version`. I have also checked the output folder I specified and it does not contain a PDF file so something bad is going on.

How can I trace this error? I literally have no idea what's happening, so I have no way of tracing the error.

Comment: What does `which wkhtmltopdf` tell you? Try running `wkhtmltopdf 2>err.txt 1>out.txt` - do you get anything into err.txt or out.txt?  Try running `./wkhtmltopdf-i386` (meaning run it directly instead of through PATH), what does that tell you? Your box output looks a very weird, because it kind of looks like it does start the process but there's no output or maybe wkhtmltopdf vomits something to STDERR and your console refuses to show it to you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Nenotlep. I have just tried those commands `sudo /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf 2>errrrrrrr.txt 1>outtttttt.txt` but there is no output in the .txt files, but the files are created. Any ideas?

Comment: That is just.. super weird :D I'm stumped. After running wkhtmltopdf, if you do `ps aux | grep wkhtmltopdf` for example, does it say that it is still running (I'm think maybe if somehow imploded and started running in background and froze)? Does running `fg` after it say anything? Does `tail /var/log/dmesg` output anything related to wkhtmltopdf? What about `tail /var/log/messages`? Sorry for this kind of shotgun debugging but this is just so weird :D.

Comment: Also, you could try the latest version 1.11.0_rc1 instead of 0.9.9 from https://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-i386.tar.bz2 and see if that works better for you.